# Why absence of semicolon in node (Javascript) does not throw an error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, syntax

I am executing following code

```
console.log('hello');
console.log('hello 2')
```

In above code why missing a semicolon does not throw an error?

Comment: Because semicolons in Javascript are optional.

Comment: [*"JavaScript applications consist of statements with an appropriate syntax. A single statement may span multiple lines. Multiple statements may occur on a single line if each statement is separated by a semicolon."*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because that is automatically inserted by compiler. Semicolon is optional in JavaScript and added to maintain code readability and termed as good coding practice. Please note, if two statement are in one line then semicolon is not optional, and you need to put it over there. like below

```
var i = 0; i++
```

Comment: In the second statement you contradict what you said in the first statement. The semicolon in Javascript separates two statements on the same line. It is not optional.

Comment: Yes, I said the same thing. Semicolon in not optional in case of same line.